# toggleClass() not working in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I've added `jQuery` in script and used

```
 import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

as well. I've also added `jQuery` in the HTML file.

But my `toggleClass()` function is not working. When I checked the console, it didn't show any error. It was just empty.

Below is my HTML and ts code:

**HTML Code:**

```
 <div class="web" (click) = "myFunc()">
    <p>
        Web Development&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       $300
    </p>
 </div>
 <div class="design" (click) = "myFunc()">
    <p>
      Design &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      $400
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="integration" (click) = "myFunc()">
     <p>
        Integration &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      $20
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="training" (click) = "myFunc()">
    <p> 
     Training &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      $500
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="total">
   Total &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   $0
</div>
```

**ts Code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
//declare var jquery:any;
//declare var $ :any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  myFunc() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes no sense using jQuery for this when it is trivial using angular for it. Not to mention that `this` isn't an element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `jquery`, just change your click binding on view to `(click)="myFunc($event)"`, and on `myFunc` change to:

```
myFunc(e) {
    const target: HTMLElement = e.target;
    target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may not be working because `$(this)` is referring to the current class instance.

you need to refer the source element in the `jquery` to work properly. Pass `'$event'` object to your function from the template and get the target object inside the function:

```
<div class="web" (click) = "myFunc($event)">

myFunc(event: any) {
  $(event.target).toggleClass("active");
}
```

See this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsely1