# Change background color of the button on click

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

I have a button that changed its text to `enable` and `disable` on click.

How can I also change the button color,

For e.g. change to Green on `enable` and Red on `disable`

```
<button (click)="enableDisableRule()">{{status}}</button>
```

Component

```
toggle = true;
status = 'Enable'; 

enableDisableRule(job) {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    this.status = this.toggle ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `ngClass`

Comment: You can use this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688460/toggleclass-not-working-in-angular-4/51688858#51688858)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ngClass directive for that purpose using two different css classes that will be triggered based on the boolean value of toggle :

template:

```
<button 
    (click)="enableDisableRule()" 
    [ngClass]="{'green' : toggle, 'red': !toggle}">
    {{status}}
</button>
```

css

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

ts

```
toggle = true;
status = 'Enable'; 

enableDisableRule(job) {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    this.status = this.toggle ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/38xzry6qvq)

Comment: Perfect but I have 4 buttons and I need to change color button2 for green and button3 return the color. For Example: green, green, red, green....Click in button green change for red and need the button 3 change the color, Do you understand?

Comment: That is a different scenario in comparison with the current question. You should ask it in a new thread.

Comment: @kboul how would you do this if you have multiple buttons and want the color to change for the background color of the button you click? Right now with this current code, it changes the bg color of all my buttons

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to change the background color, you can use style binding:

```
<button [style.background-color]="toggle ? 'green' : 'red'" (click)="enableDisableRule()">
  {{status}}
</button>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9y2jec) for a demo.

Comment: I have a similar case, The original color is nothing, click once should be red, one more click should be green. Can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngClass] on your button to apply the appropriate styles class.

```
<button (click)="enableDisableRule()"
    [ngClass]="{'enabled': toggle, 'disabled': !toggle}">
        {{status}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your default `toggle` was true, that default class is `.toggle`. Use the Css priority to replace `[ngClass]`.

```
<button (click)="enableDisableRule()" class="toggle" [class.btn--disable]="!toggle">{{status}}</button>
```

For the Css order, `toggle` would be above `disable`.

```
.toggle { background-color:green; }
.btn--disable { background-color:red; }
```