# Change background color of buttons onclick

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have two buttons called **YES** and **NO** whose color(i,e background-color) is light like this:

[image]

> When the user click **YES**

- **YES** button background color should change to green (i,e success) and **NO** should be in light color like this:

[image]

> When the user click **No**

- **NO** button background color should change to red (i,e danger) and **Yes** should be in light color like this:

[image]

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-vr5byq?file=src/app/home/home.page.html)**

while surfing i saw this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716059/change-background-color-of-the-button-on-click)**. Here they are changing only one **button** color on **click**. But for my requirement both the **button** color should change on **click**.

CODE

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item lines="none">
  <ion-button class="btn-1" expand="full" color="light" >Yes</ion-button>
   <ion-button class="btn-2" expand="full"  color="light" >No</ion-button> 
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-1{
width:45%;
float:left;
padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
.btn-2{
width:45%;
float:right;
padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

**TS**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.css'],
})
export class HomePage {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 values means you can't use a boolean. But you can use a number :

```js
buttonValue = 0;
```

```html
<ion-button class="btn-1" expand="full" [color]="buttonValue > 0 ? 'success' : 'light'" (click)="buttonValue = 1">Yes</ion-button>
<ion-button class="btn-2" expand="full" [color]="buttonValue < 0 ? 'danger' : 'light'" (click)="buttonValue = -1">No</ion-button>
```

Comment: @SGR No problem, if you feel your question has been answered, consider accepting one of the answers !

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

TS:

```
isYesClicked:boolean = false
isNoClicked:boolean = false
```

HTML:

```
<ion-button class="btn-1" expand="full" (click)="isYesClicked=true;isNoClicked=false" [color]="isYesClicked?'success':'light'"  >Yes</ion-button>


<ion-button class="btn-2" expand="full"  color="light" (click)="isYesClicked=false;isNoClicked=true" [color]="isNoClicked?'danger':'light'">No</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try this code or follow this link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-672zlv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts):

edit your template **home.page.html**

```
<ion-button (click)="activeNow('green')" class="btn-1" expand="full" [color]="(selectItem==='green')? 'success':'light'" >Yes</ion-button>
<ion-button (click)="activeNow('red')" class="btn-2" expand="full"  [color]="(selectItem==='red')? 'danger':'light'"  >No</ion-button>
```

And update the **home.page.ts**

```
selectItem:string='';
activeNow(item:string) {
  this.selectItem=item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class on click with `ngClass` like this

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-button
      [ngClass]="yesButtonTriggered ? 'greenButton': 'light'"
      (click)="yesButton()"
      class="btn-1"
      expand="full"
      color="light"
    >Yes</ion-button>
    <ion-button
      [ngClass]="noButtonTriggered ? 'redButton': 'light'"
      (click)="noButton()"
      class="btn-2"
      expand="full"
      color="light"
    >No</ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

And in your TS

```js
  yesButtonTriggered = false;
  noButtonTriggered = false;

  yesButton() {
    // do your stuff
    this.yesButtonTriggered = true;
    this.noButtonTriggered = false;
  }

  noButton() {
    // do your stuff
    this.noButtonTriggered = true;
    this.yesButtonTriggered = false;
  }
```